# Deep Linking or Dynamic Linking to open applicaiton in Intune portal

Tags: android, ios, deep-linking, dynamic-linking, intune

I'm looking for information about if it is possible to create a Deep Linking or Dynamic Linking in Intune Portal for Android/iOS?

When a user clicks a Deep Linking or Dynamic Linking it will redirect to an application page in the Intune Portal if the application is not installed, or open the application if has been installed.

I know Deep Linking or Dynamic Linking works to open an application in an Application Portal Apple Store or Google Play Store, but I want the link to open Intune Portal instead of those stores.

Comment: Use firebase, it's really simple and powerful. This is document: https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links

Comment: @HoàngVũAnh I've read that but I can't find if it will open an application in Intune portal. As far as I know Firebase Dynamic link will open Apple Store or Google Play Store. Are you sure Firebase Dynamic Link support Intune?